# issue with autocomplete with 6 rows in mysql

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, jquery-autocomplete

Im working with autocomplete and is working nice but when I use it with more than one row the results are sometimes in the same line... can you help me to show one result per line and only one match result(when in DB is many time repeated) and not 3 or more same word...

here is a capture to show you the issue:

[image]

I need to show only one word when in the DB is repeated many times...I know this can solved with "DISTINCT" but when is more than one row in the table the code in my case don't work..

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'cmedic', '21M1Sy', 'smedic');
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
$text = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['term']);
$query = "SELECT diagnostico, diagnostico1, diagnostico2, diagnostico3, diagnostico4, diagnostico5, diagnostico6 FROM DIAGNOSTICO WHERE diagnostico LIKE '%$text%' OR diagnostico1 LIKE '%$text%' OR diagnostico2 LIKE '%$text%' OR diagnostico3 LIKE '%$text%' OR diagnostico4 LIKE '%$text%' OR diagnostico5 LIKE '%$text%' OR diagnostico6 LIKE '%$text%'";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$json = '[';
$first = true;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    if (!$first) { $json .=  ','; } else { $first = false; }
    $json .= '{"value":"'.$row['diagnostico'].''.$row['diagnostico1'].''.$row['diagnostico2'].''.$row['diagnostico3'].''.$row['diagnostico4'].''.$row['diagnostico5'].''.$row['diagnostico6'].'"}';
}
$json .= ']';
echo $json;
?>
```

Here is the script:

```
$('#auto').autocomplete({
    source: "scripts/nostic.php",
    minLength: 3
});
```

And the input with the ID:

```
<input type="text"  name="diagnostico1" id="auto"/>
```

Comment: Why are you formatting the JSON yourself instead of using `json_encode()`?

Comment: @Barmar to be honest I followed a tutorial...I am noob with this and I learned with the tutorials

Comment: Programming isn't about cutting and pasting from tutorials, it's about learning the basics and composing them yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you need. It pivots all the `diagnosticoN` columns into one column, and uses `UNION DISTINCT` to filter out duplicates.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'cmedic', '21M1Sy', 'smedic');
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
$query = "SELECT diagnostico FROM DIAGNOSTICO WHERE diagnostico LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')
          UNION DISTINCT
          SELECT diagnostico2 FROM DIAGNOSTICO WHERE diagnostico2 LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')
          UNION DISTINCT
          SELECT diagnostico3 FROM DIAGNOSTICO WHERE diagnostico3 LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')
          UNION DISTINCT
          SELECT diagnostico4 FROM DIAGNOSTICO WHERE diagnostico4 LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')
          UNION DISTINCT
          SELECT diagnostico5 FROM DIAGNOSTICO WHERE diagnostico5 LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')
          UNION DISTINCT
          SELECT diagnostico6 FROM DIAGNOSTICO WHERE diagnostico6 LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('ssssss', $_GET['term'], $_GET['term'], $_GET['term'], $_GET['term'], $_GET['term'], $_GET['term']);
$result = $stmt->execute();
$json = array();
$stmt->bind_result($diagnostico);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $json[] = array('value' => $diagnostico);
}
echo json_encode($json);
```

I also show how to use parametrized queries instead of interpolating strings.

Comment: thank you for your support.I see that you change the code to pdo I think?

Comment: No, that's mysqli. They both support parametrized queries.

Comment: I have this error and I don't really know how fix it.. `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/xx/public_html/xxxxx/scripts/diagnost2.php on line 17`..that line is this: `$stmt = $mysql->prepare($query);`

Comment: sorry for bother you but I am tried to fix the issue above with not success... I inclusive change the sentence = `$stmt = $mysql->prepare($query);` to `$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);`  the change is in mysql to mysqli and when I change it the error change to this warning = PHP Warning:  mysqli_stmt::execute() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given in /home/xx/public_html/xxxxx/scripts/diagnost2.php on line 19.... this is the line 19 `$result = $stmt->execute($query);` can you give me a clue with this? Best regards!

Comment: That was a mistake, there shouldn't be any arguments. I've corrected the answer.